# usbip: automatically pass keyboard between computers

Tags: linux, usb, keyboard, linux-kernel

I have a wireless usb keyboard which I would like to use at two computers without constantly shifting the receiver. Possible solution: usbip. However, some problems:

1. Why does `usbip unbind` not allow the keyboard to be used locally? Right now, I have to physically unplug/replug the receiver for the keyboard to work again. Is there something I can do to force "re-initialization"?
2. Are the `usbip bind` busids consistent across reboot? I've seen them change in `lsusb` across unplug/replug yet the busids remain constant in `usbip bind`, so mabe they're derived from the actual IDs. If not, how do I derive the `usbip` busid from the actual usb ID?
3. Is unbinding an attached device "bad"?

If these concerns are solvable, I'll probably create a json-rpc server to remotely manage usbip:

- enumerate devices, annotated with bind information
- bind/unbind devices
- attach/detach devices

And the client won't perform any operations until it successfully connects to both the local and remote servers (a keyboard swap requires both local and remote manipulation).

Right now this is still in the air, so any suggestions welcome. Though it would be nice if these operations were already handled by the `usbip` protocol.

Comment: There is a software-based solution for it.. one I personally used is Synergy/Symless - not free but very handy. If you prefer to use usbip / free solution - I will leave it to others to have a read and hopefully help you better.

Comment: Googling for ["kvm switch software linux"](https://www.google.com/search?q=kvm+switch+software+linux") or similar may find ready-made solutions for your problem.

Comment: `x2x` *might* be applicable, which I overlooked and will soon test. I'm looking for a keyboard-only solution and `x2x` may require a mouse (that is, I want a keybinding to switch monitors - maybe `x2x` with some X11 automation utility?). A `usbip` approach is as-of-yet the only possible solution on Wayland, and I think could also be a bit of fun. That said, an answer would benefit everyone - least of all `usbip` users and maybe some Linux USB users tired of re-plugging unresponsive USB devices - not just for those looking to replace the dated `x2x`.

Comment: As a kvm switch `usbip` *does* lack encryption.

Comment: I've tried `x2x` and found that it conflicts with screensavers. When grabbing the mouse for the remote display, it prevents the local screensaver from activating. Worse, if only the keyboard is grabbed (i.e. when not using directional parameters) the screensaver will still activate and block remote input, usually at the most inconvenient of times. Keyboard input also seemed to stutter, as though it were being batched - intermittent periods of lag. Turns out this can be solved by bypassing the X11 SECURITY extensions, i.e. `ssh -Y`.